# how to parse multiple attributes in xml jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, html

i have created a autocomplete search box and that display only name list , **i want to show all data using xml file**. for example- name, city, country, etc.
how to solve this...? please help me.

my code is...
 in html

```
<form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="search_results.html">
<label for="searchBox">Keyword Search</label>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString" />

<button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Sumbit</button>
</form>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArr = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml", // change to full path of file on server
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml,
        complete: setupAC,
        failure: function(data) {
            alert("XML File could not be found");
            }
    });

    function parseXml(xml)
    {
        //find every query value
        $(xml).find("info").each(function()
        {
            myArr.push($(this).attr("name"));
        }); 
    }

    function setupAC() {
        $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#searchForm").submit();
                }
        });
    }
 });
```

and in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<info name="jatin" value="IP"  city="Pune" country="india" />
<info name="kishor" value="WY" city="Mumbai" country="india" />
<info name="rahul" value="AL" city="Latur" country="india" />
<info name="dnyanesh" value="WY" city="punjab" country="india" />
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml", // change to full path of file on server
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        parseXml(xml); // calling parseXml and pass xml into it.
        setupAC();
    },
    failure: function(data) {
        alert("XML File could not be found");
    }
});
```

Updated for city/country/name search with snippet,

```js
$(function() {

  var myArr = [],
    xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><info name="jatin" value="IP"  city="Pune" country="india" /><info name="kishor" value="WY" city="Mumbai" country="india" /><info name="rahul" value="AL" city="Latur" country="india" /><info name="dnyanesh" value="WY" city="punjab" country="india" /></data>';

  function parseXml(xml) {
    //find every query value
    $(xml).find("info").each(function() {
      myArr.push({
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        city: $(this).attr('city'),
        country: $(this).attr('country'),
        value: $(this).attr('value')
      });
    });
  }

  function setupAC() {
    $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response($.grep(myArr, function(v) {
          return matcher.test(v.name) || matcher.test(v.city) || matcher.test(v.country);
        }));
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);
      }
    });
  }
  parseXml(xml);
  setupAC();

});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input id="searchBox" type="text">
```

Comment: i use this code but still, display only name...not a city or country.